# Cannot hear myself through headphones

Tags: windows-xp, audio, microphone

I cannot hear my mic in my headphones in Windows XP. The mic works fine and I can communicate with people using VOIP, but I cannot hear myself in the headphones, which is a problem because they are noise canceling.

The normal solution is to make sure the mic is a playback device, but according to my system it is. This is what my mixer looks like:

[image]

As can be seen above my microphone is not muted, so I should be able to hear it, no? My volume panel looks like this:

[image]

The "playback" options in the standard windows sound device control panels are grayed out. Also, there is no "Listen to this device" option for the microphone. The dxdiag for computer gives the following information about the HyperX USB audio device:

[image]

Comment: Is this a new headset?  One of the HyperX core, other, models?  Did you just 'plug and play' them?

Comment: It is a HyperX, I just plugged it in to the USB port as can be inferred from the DirectX diagnostics screen included above.

Comment: What I was getting at is whether or not you installed any specific drivers for it, the current driver is from 2008.  I would go to their site and get the latest drivers for that specific model and see if that gets you any where.

Comment: I had this issue, all I did was download the audio driver by Realtek and installed that, it provided the What you hear option

Comment: Are you sure the microphone is labeled as "microphone" and not "line in"? https://www.onlinemictest.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/microphone-marked-windows-xp.png

(Check to see if there are any strange options there that aren't ticked)

Also sounds like you're using a USB headset, that is probably related to this problem (USB headsets double as USB soundcards needing their own drivers, your headset simply might not be fully compatible with XP)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not activated by default because it can become very annoying. You could use [VB Audio Virtual Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm) or [Matrix Mic Player](http://download.cnet.com/Matrix-Mic-Player/3000-2170_4-10977348.html).

Comment: That worked, great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you mute the microphone, that just means it won't record anything. What you want is to send the microphone sound through to your speakers. Here is how you do it in xp:

Right click the sound icon in the tray icon, go to recording devices, right click your microphone, advanced settings, listen tab, listen to this device.

Comment: There is no sound icon in the tray. I cannot add it to the tray because the control where this is done is grayed out (see image in answer above).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be problem with quite old XP windows.

Also, have you tried to connect to another PC with different OS?